# Write in several sizes in multilingual documents with polyglossia

Tags: fontsize, polyglossia

I have to write, in the front page of a document, and in other pages, sentences written in english, in the font "Times new roman", and sentences written in Arabic, in the font "Traditional Arabic", in several sizes, 14,16,18,22... What is the best way to do that?

I use the `polyglossia` package, and compile texts with XeLaTeX.

I give here some own tries and remarks about this task. Note that (I think that!) one can use the font he/she has.

Here is the .tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{english}
\noindent 
One can write multi-lingual documents, and math equations, by using the polyglossia package, and compile it with \XeLaTeX, in several sizes. The basic size is 12pt.
\end{english}
\hrule

{\centering 

\LR{Text in 14pt is obtained by using the command $\backslash$large:

{\large A latin text, in size 14 pt.}

An arabic text, in size 14 pt, is the following centered text:}

 {\large 
نص عربي في حجم 14.
}

\hrule

\LR{Text in 17pt is obtained by using the command $\backslash$Large:

{\Large A latin text, in size 17 pt.}

An arabic text, in size 17 pt, is the following centered text:}

 {\Large 
نص عربي في حجم 17.
}

\hrule

\LR{For larger sizes, we use the command, for example, $\backslash$fontsize\{18\}\{22\}, which puts the size to 18pt for arabic and english characters, but has no effect under the package polyglossia, else if we put the characters under the commands \\
$\backslash$begin\{Arabic\} ...$\backslash$end\{Arabic\}, and $\backslash$begin\{english\} ...$\backslash$end\{english\}, respectively. I give examples of compilations:

\hrule
{\fontsize{18}{22} A latin text, under the command $\backslash$fontsize\{18\}\{22\}, and outside $\backslash$begin\{english\} ...$\backslash$end\{english\}.}
\hrule

 {\fontsize{18}{22} \begin{english}
 A latin text, under the command $\backslash$fontsize\{18\}\{22\}, and $\backslash$begin\{english\} ...$\backslash$end\{english\}.
 \end{english}}
\hrule

 Arabic text, under the command $\backslash$fontsize\{18\}\{22\}, and outside $\backslash$begin\{Arabic\} ...$\backslash$end\{Arabic\}:
}

{\fontsize{18}{22}
نص عربي في حجم 18.
}

\hrule 
 \LR{ Arabic text, under the command $\backslash$fontsize\{18\}\{22\}, and $\backslash$begin\{Arabic\} ...$\backslash$end\{Arabic\}:}

{\fontsize{18}{22}
\begin{Arabic}
نص عربي في حجم 18.
\end{Arabic}}

\par}

\end{document}
```

and its compilation:

[image]

Comment: You have missed selecting the font (ie, `\fontsize{18}{22}\selectfont`).

Comment: @JavierBezos Yes many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to specify font size. It depends on what you want to do.

`\fontsize` could be used for particular cases not covered by the document class.

The relative size commands (tiny, small, large, Large, huge etc) are designed to keep the document design harmonious.

Package `fontspec`'s `Scale=` option is very useful, I find. Plus all its other options, like specifying different fonts for different sizes with the `SizeFeatures` option. And many other things as well. `Polyglossia` very handily loads `fontspec` in the background.

Alternatively, you can also hard-code specific font sizes with the `\font` command, if you want.

Illustration shows `\font` commands (top) and `fontspec`'s `Scale=` (and `Colour=`) option (bottom). Text is from the solar system Wikipedia article. Font is Times New Roman, which contains Arabic, Armenian, Cyrillic, Greek and Coptic, Hebrew, Latin and IPA scripts.

[image: font sizes]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\font\ffonta="Times New Roman" at 14pt
\font\ffontb="Times New Roman" at 18pt
\font\ffontc="Times New Roman" at 24pt
\font\ffontd="Times New Roman" at 36pt
\font\ffonte="Times New Roman" at 48pt

\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\fgfonta[Scale=1.0,Script=Arabic,Colour=brown]{Times New Roman}
\newfontface\fgfontb[Scale=1.4,Script=Arabic,Colour=red]{Times New Roman}
\newfontface\fgfontc[Scale=2.3,Script=Arabic,Colour=green]{Times New Roman}
\newfontface\fgfontd[Scale=3.5,Script=Arabic,Colour=blue]{Times New Roman}
\newfontface\fgfonte[Scale=5.0,Script=Arabic,Colour=violet]{Times New Roman}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}%Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\ffonta المجموعة الشمسية

\ffontb المجموعة الشمسية

\ffontc المجموعة الشمسية

\ffontd المجموعة الشمسية

\ffonte المجموعة الشمسية

*

\fgfonta المجموعة الشمسية

\fgfontb المجموعة الشمسية

\fgfontc المجموعة الشمسية

\fgfontd المجموعة الشمسية

\fgfonte المجموعة الشمسية


\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Edited to add:
Boldface, using font family, instead of font face:

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\fgfonta[Scale=1.0,Script=Arabic,Colour=brown]{Noto Naskh Arabic}
\newfontfamily\fgfontb[Scale=1.4,Script=Arabic,Colour=red]{Noto Naskh Arabic}
\newfontfamily\fgfontc[Scale=2.3,Script=Arabic,Colour=green]{Noto Naskh Arabic}
\newfontfamily\fgfontd[Scale=3.5,Script=Arabic,Colour=blue]{Noto Naskh Arabic}
\newfontfamily\fgfonte[Scale=5.0,Script=Arabic,Colour=violet]{Noto Naskh Arabic}

\setmainfont{Noto Naskh Arabic}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}

\fgfonta المجموعة الشمسية

\bfseries\fgfonta المجموعة الشمسية

\mdseries
\fgfontb المجموعة الشمسية

\bfseries\fgfontb المجموعة الشمسية
\mdseries

\fgfontc المجموعة الشمسية

\bfseries\fgfontc المجموعة الشمسية
\mdseries

\fgfontd المجموعة الشمسية

\bfseries\fgfontd المجموعة الشمسية
\mdseries


\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: boldface]

Edited to add:

Using two font declarations, same scale but different colours, the `kern` and `llap` commands give an interesting effect.

[image: kern and llap]

Added:
Regular and Boldface example:

[image: Bold]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\fgfontc[Scale=2.3,Script=Arabic,Colour=green]{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\fgfontck[Scale=2.3,Script=Arabic,Colour=blue]{Traditional Arabic}\newfontfamily\fgfontd[Scale=4.5,Script=Arabic,Colour=red]{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\fgfontdk[Scale=4.5,Script=Arabic,Colour=blue]{Traditional Arabic}

\setmainfont{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Noto Serif}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}


\begin{english}
Traditional Arabic font,\\
with \textbackslash kern and \textbackslash llap \\ commands. \\ \ \\
\end{english}

\fgfontc المجموعة الشمسية\kern-1.25pt\llap{\fgfontck المجموعة الشمسية}


\fgfontd المجموعة الشمسية\kern-1.45pt\llap{\fgfontdk المجموعة الشمسية}

\end{center}

\begin{english}
Traditional Arabic font, regular and bold:
\end{english}


ححح خخخ ههه ععع غغغ ففف ىىى لالالا ششش صصص 

\bfseries
ححح خخخ ههه ععع غغغ ففف ىىى لالالا ششش صصص 

\mdseries\Large
ححح خخخ ههه ععع غغغ ففف ىىى لالالا ششش صصص 

\bfseries
ححح خخخ ههه ععع غغغ ففف ىىى لالالا ششش صصص 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry to review after some time, but the font commands has no effect with bold commands `\bf` or `\textbf`. Are there special sizing commands for fonts in bold too?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouma, Use a font family that contains bold face, e.g., Noto Naskh Arabic.

Comment: How can I know that a font uses bold face..? I must use `Traditional arabic` in arabic and `Times new roman` in  english

Comment: In Windows (c:\windows\fonts), Times New Roman family is made up of four faces: Times New Roman Bold (timesbd.ttf), Times New Roman Bold Italic (timesbi.ttf), Times New Roman Italic (timesi.ttf), Times New Roman Regular (times.ttf); and Traditional Arabic family has two faces: Traditional Arabic (tradbdo.ttf) and Traditional Arabic Regular (trado.ttf).

Comment: So as I understand, your commands can't be used in bold with the Traditional Arabic font. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Faouzi Bellalouna, Traditional Arabic font has boldface. Very easy. To use it, the font file (timesbd.ttf) must be installed on your system, it must be visible to Tex, and you must use the appropriate commands or switches. See updated answer for example of use.

Comment: All is good now. Many thanks